# PHP - Dealing with array

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose I have an array as below, how can I "check if vid = 2, then get/echo tid"?

```
Array
(
    [29] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 29
            [vid] => 2
            [name] => notebook
            [description] => 
            [weight] => 0
            [language] => 
            [trid] => 0
        )

    [97] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 97
            [vid] => 1
            [name] => DELL
            [description] => 
            [weight] => 0
            [language] => 
            [trid] => 0
        )

)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
foreach($vids as $vid){
    if($vid->vid == 2){
        echo $vid->tid;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

```
  foreach($tid as $key => $value){
    if($value->vid == 2){
        echo $value->tid;
    }
  }
```

Comment: How is this different from Justin Lucas' much earlier answer? The `$key =>` part is completely redundant.

Comment: You can try Justin Lucas answer and you won't get the correct solution

Comment: Nowhere in your question does it say your array is called `$tid` and not `$vids`. How are we supposed to know?

Comment: It just a name, you can give the array name nid, pid or whatever... I don't know why you doubt with it

Comment: Why do you say Justin Lucas' answer is incorrect? It looks to be the same as this answer.

Comment: I don't know why *you* doubt it.

Comment: "You can try Justin Lucas answer and you won't get the correct solution" - that would imply your answer is also incorrect since it's completely identical.